# how do I write this JSON string in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

How do I write this JSON string in vb.net with out a serializer or a third party DLL?

```
Dim myString As String = [ { 'a': 'zzz'},{ 'b': 'zzz'}{ 'c': 'zzz'} ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim myString As String = "[ { 'a': 'zzz'},{ 'b': 'zzz'},{ 'c': 'zzz'} ]"
```

You should add a comma between b and c

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim myString As String = "[ { 'a': 'zzz'},{ 'b': 'zzz'}{ 'c': 'zzz'} ]"
```

Comment: That seems simplistic, but if it isn't what you were looking for, please add more detail to your question. Thanks :)